# Switch case warning in swift

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement

I have switch condition on Int32 attribute of core-data entity as

```
switch location.userLocationLike?.likeStatusId {
            case 1 as Int32:
                view.lblLike.text = "LIKED"
            case 2 as Int32:
                view.lblLike.text = "OKAY"
            case 3 as Int32:
                view.lblLike.text = "DISLIKE"
            default:
                view.lblLike.text = "LIKE"
            }
```

If I don't type cast value as Int32 than it shows error, And if I convert it to Int32 than warning. Can anyone please explain me what is the best way to write Switch-case.
[image]

Comment: can you print this location.userLocationLike?.likeStatusId

Comment: try this `case 1 as Int`

Comment: Anbu,  case 1 as Int: --> is Throwing warning like "Cast from Int32 to unrelated type Int always fails"

Comment: then you need to unwrap in safe and check with int

Comment: it is possible to attach the project

Comment: Hmmm, I was thinking for same initially now going to do that but we need solution for that in case anyone has big int value like Int 32 or Int 64.
Thank you

Comment: Sorry cant send project file :|

Comment: Just checked the answer of Vadian, Its working fine.(y), May be the issue of optional Value assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is misleading,  you cannot switch on an optional with non-optional cases, optional bind (or even forced unwrap) `userLocationLike`, according to the warnings the `as Int32` casts are meaningless.

```
if let likeStatus = location.userLocationLike {

    switch likeStatus.likeStatusId {
        case 1: view.lblLike.text = "LIKED"
        case 2: view.lblLike.text = "OKAY"
        case 3  view.lblLike.text = "DISLIKE"
        default: view.lblLike.text = "LIKE"
    }
}
```

Comment: You *can* switch on an optional with the appropriate pattern, e.g. `case 1?:`

Comment: I don't think the error is misleading. The only problem is the question mark at the end tends to get lost. If it said "expression of type Int cannot match optional Int32" I don't think anybody would have a problem, but it still says the same thing.

Comment: If I'm not casting my case value then code throws an error